# FTP command "get *.txt" error "550 File not Found"

Tags: batch-file, download, ftp

My problem appears when I try to download files with a batch file over the FTP.

```
OPEN 192.168.0.1
test
password
lcd Download-dir
cd /filedir
BINARY
get *.txt
```

Everything works well up to the moment he try to find the File. At that moment he call the

> Error 550 File not Found.

When I try the same with

```
get Test.txt
```

It will work fine.

Every tutorial use the `*` as wildcard but why does it not work for me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`get` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-get) in `ftp.exe` does not support wildcards.

You have to use the [`mget` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mget):

```
mget *.txt
```